# Efficient way to draw Ellipse with OpenGL or D3D

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, geometry

There is a fast way to draw circle like this

```
void DrawCircle(float cx, float cy, float r, int num_segments) 
{ 
    float theta = 2 * 3.1415926 / float(num_segments); 
    float c = cosf(theta);//precalculate the sine and cosine
    float s = sinf(theta);
    float t;

    float x = r;//we start at angle = 0 
    float y = 0; 

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); 
    for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++) 
    { 
        glVertex2f(x + cx, y + cy);//output vertex 

        //apply the rotation matrix
        t = x;
        x = c * x - s * y;
        y = s * t + c * y;
    } 
    glEnd(); 
}
```

I am wondering if there is a similar way to draw ellipse where its major/minor axes vector and size are both known.

Comment: That code will never be "efficient" as long as you use immediate mode (glBegin, glVertex, glEnd, etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to draw a curve in openGL, just a lot of straight lines.  But if you used vertex buffer objects then you won't have to send each vertex to the graphics card which will be much faster.

[My Java Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550114/converting-opengl-draw-lists-to-vertex-arrays-or-vbos/5550185#5550185)

Answer (score 8):

If we take your example we can use an internal radius of 1 and apply horizontal/vertical radius separately in order to get an ellipse:

```
void DrawEllipse(float cx, float cy, float rx, float ry, int num_segments) 
{ 
    float theta = 2 * 3.1415926 / float(num_segments); 
    float c = cosf(theta);//precalculate the sine and cosine
    float s = sinf(theta);
    float t;

    float x = 1;//we start at angle = 0 
    float y = 0; 

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); 
    for(int ii = 0; ii < num_segments; ii++) 
    { 
        //apply radius and offset
        glVertex2f(x * rx + cx, y * ry + cy);//output vertex 

        //apply the rotation matrix
        t = x;
        x = c * x - s * y;
        y = s * t + c * y;
    } 
    glEnd(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the ellipse is ((x-cx)/a)^2 + ((y-cy)/b)^2 = 1 then change the glVertex2f call to
glVertext2d(a*x + cx, b*y + cy);

To simplify the sums, lets suppose for a while that the ellipse is centred at the origin.

If the ellipse is rotated so that the semi-major axis (of length a) makes an angle theta with the x axis, then the ellipse is the set of points p so that p' * inv(C) * p = 1, where C is the matrix R(theta) * D * R(theta)' where ' denotes transpose and D is the diagonal matrix with entries a*a,b*b (b the length of the semi-minor axis). If L is the cholesky factor (eg [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition)) of C then the ellipse is the set of points p so that (inv(L) * p)'*(inv(L) *p ) = 1, so that L maps the unit circle to the ellipse. If we have computed L as ( u 0 ; v w) (just once, before the loop) then the glVertexf call becomes glVertex2f( u*x + cx, v*x + w*y + cy);

L can be calculated like this (where C is cos(theta) and S is sin(theta)):

u = sqrt( C*C*a*a + S*S*b*b); v = C*S*(a*a-b*b); w = a*b/u;

Comment: I think this only works when the ellipse axes are aligned to the X and Y axes (if even then?).