# How to Render an Ellipse with Google RenderScript

Tags: renderscript

I've checked the Android SDK and also performed a Google search on this topic, but to no avail.  Does anyone have a code sample or relevant links?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use Renderscript to draw graphics. It was an experimental feature and as of Android 4.1 it is deprecated: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Renderscript

For hardware accelerated graphics, you should use OpenGL ES instead.

Answer (score 2):

With Renderscript you can do this two ways, draw an ellipse-like mesh or draw a rectangle with the texture of an ellipse.  If it works for your problem, drawing the texture on a rectangle will be a lot simpler than drawing an ellipse as a mesh.

If you do need to draw the ellipse as a mesh, remember that you only have points, lines, and triangles.  This question might help: [Effecient way to draw Ellipse with OpenGL or D3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886628/effecient-way-to-draw-ellipse-with-opengl-or-d3d)