# Converting OpenGL draw lists to vertex arrays or VBOs with C and other methods for OpenGL acceleration like geGenList

Tags: c#, opengl

I'm trying to convert a program using draw lists, to use either vertex arrays or VBOs.

```
dl = glGenLists(1)
glNewList(dl, GL_COMPILE)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
glTexCoord2f(0, 0)
glVertex2f(0, 0)
glTexCoord2f(0, 1)
glVertex2f(0, height)
glTexCoord2f(1, 1)
glVertex2f(width, height)
glTexCoord2f(1, 0)
glVertex2f(width, 0)
glEnd()
glEndList()
```

I have found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550114/converting-opengl-draw-lists-to-vertex-arrays-or-vbos)  I could not pass it to c#. And I need one examaple of use it. There is an easier way to do this?
I need this to increase the fps of my application,I appreciate if you tell me other methods for OpenGL acceleration  like  geGenList

Comment: i do not understand how to use the functions

Comment: Can check [Vbo on NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/vertex_buffer_objects/22002/). There is aldo download section for C# too.